# C# UWP. raspberry pi проблема с экраном

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi

Суть в том что есть экран `7"`от `waveshare`, который работает нормально на `10586` версии. Но на последней, не адекватно.

Событие `tapped` срабатывает через куча нажатий. А событие `Pointer` всё отлично. 
Суть в том что `tapped` прикручено ко всем стандартным кнопкам и т.д (от самой ОС).

Нужно как то решить эту проблему. Есть как вариант отлавливать событие `pointer` и с помощью его создавать событие `tapped`.

Как такую магию можно реализовать? Либо может какие другие варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз отсеивать лишние Tapped. Фильтровать по источнику или еще как-нибудь. Они все одинаковые? Может сенсор бракованный?